# How to Sanitise Search Bar String in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Creating a search bar to query a MySQL database using an html form and PHP. The PHP code is returning rows from the database, but I'm struggling to sanitise the input string from the search bar. Please can someone recommend an effective way to do this for my PHP code?

I have tried a number of functions from the book 'PHP, MySQL & Javascript - 5th Edition' and functions Filter_var and htmlEntities.

And I am still able to enter backslashes or html entities that amend the echoed html output from the search function.

```
<?php


echo <<<_End


<form action="InsertLike2.php" method="post"><pre>

<textarea name="Message" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Search">

</pre></form>

_End;

 require_once 'login.php';
 $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(!empty($_POST))
{
      $searchStr = $_POST['Message'];
      $searchStr = htmlentities($searchStr);
      $searchStr = filter_var($searchStr, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $aKeyword = explode(" ", $searchStr);

      $query ="SELECT * FROM MessageMain WHERE MessageText like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'";

     for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
            $query .= " OR MessageText like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
        }
      }

     $result = $conn->query($query);
     echo "<br>You have searched for keywords: " . $_POST['Message'];

     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row_count=0;
        echo "<br>Result Found: ";
        While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
            $row_count++;                         
            echo "<pre> Message". "</pre>". nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['MessageText'],ENT_COMPAT|ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8") );

        }

    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Result Found: NONE";
    }
}

//Examples of different functions used

function get_post($conn, $var)
{
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}

function mysql_entities_fix_string($connection,$string)
{
  return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($connection,$string));
}

function mysql_fix_string($connection,$string)
{
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
  return $connection->real_escape_string($string);
}

?>
```

I expect html entities or backslashes (injection attacks to be filtered out or made harmless).

Comment: The method is described in the manual: [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You don't need much sanitizing, just don't put the input directly in the query string.

Comment: use a `prepared statement` as opposed to embedding the variable directly in the sql

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm not sure what that means sorry. One of the things that I am finding when testing my search function online is that entering something like 'Tennis <h1>' will change the formatting of the echoed search results. I assume this is a bad sign.

Comment: @RamRaider would that resolve the threat to an XSS attack?

Comment: @RamRaider also as I'm using the explode function to create an array, I'm not sure how to use placeholders in the loop I have created.

Comment: I'm sorry that the manual entry on SQL injection is not clear to you, but it remains the biggest security hole in your code. Try to read it again. You can convert characters that have a special meaning in HTML to their "entities" with [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Use this when echoing search results, not before.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you. That helps. It’s more applying the example code in the manual to what I’m doing. It does make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

When you echo variable print out as html it doesn't weird if you unable to see escape string.

> use var_dump to see the escape string.

```
var_dump(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['MessageText'],ENT_COMPAT|ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8") ));
```

You will see the magic.